# Difference between full stack angular and meanjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, meanjs

I am pretty new to Node.JS and was trying to explore various YO generators. Could you please explain the basic differences between a Full Stack Angular Generator and MeanJS angular generator using Yeoman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full Stack Angular Generator (by [DaftMonk](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack)) and MeanJS Angular Generator are both generators for applications using MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js.

But full stack angular generator has more configurable options as compared to Meanjs angular generator. Have a look [here](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/163) at the duplicate functionality topic . Also here is a quote from daftMonk:

> I would like to talk about the direction I've been thinking about going with the fullstack generator. I don't think a behemoth generator that makes all the decisions for you is a good idea. It's fine to have it select default options, but I think almost everything should be customizable. That's why if I continue to work on this project, I would like to start breaking it up into multiple smaller generators.

Comment: Thanks a lot, selecting the link you mentioned helped me finding a very comprehensive site containing lot of information around the comparisons of various Stacks around NodeJs. Check this out http://www.dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters/